# How can I get YAML to ignore raw HTML in same file

Tags: php, html, yaml

I am trying to make a flatfile PHP blog that uses YAML to convert the entries to code, but I can't find out how to get YAML to ignore the HTML tags and everything after the second "---":

```
---
title = "Entry title"
tags = "tag1 tag2 tag3"
someInportentVariable = "Some Inportent Content"
---

<p>This is some entry content.</p>
<p>Line2.</p>
<p>Line3.</p>
<p>And so on...</p>
```

How can I be able do that?

Here's a example of what I mean: https://github.com/claco/claco.github.com/blob/master/_posts/2002-10-05-marry-a-sysadmin.textile.

**Update**: For people who wants to contact me, head over to my new stackoverflow account, [RobinLilfelt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/386719/robin-lilfelt).

Answer (score 3):

What you probably want to do is treat the HTML as [a quoted scalar literal](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760844).  You do this by starting the HTML section with `--- |` and indenting all of the lines.

e.g.:

```
---
title = "Entry title"
tags = "tag1 tag2 tag3"
someInportentVariable = "Some Inportent Content"
postBody: |
  <p>This is some entry content.</p>
  <p>Line2.</p>
  <p>Line3.</p>
  <p>And so on...</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I've asked my friend I'm working on the project with, and he says it has to be in the same format...

So I was thinking, can I use some kind of large REGEX string inside a preg_(something) or should I just split the YAML and HTML?

I've already tried preg_split, but then I have to remove the /n between the --- and the html. How can I do that without touching the other /n's?

Comment: I don't know what you mean here.  You can encode a scalar literal in your document, as I showed above (note recent edit).  If you're using some kind of additional parsing to separate items, you are throwing away the value of YAML: having a built in format that saves you from writing your own parsing stages.