# Internationalization/Translations in Ruby on Rails for images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I am using the t tags and internationalization for ruby on rails and I was wondering how I can use the internationalization for images? I have a logo that is a jpg and it is in french and I have one in english. How can I use the english.yml and french.yml files to upload different logos depending on which language people choose?

I'm very new to all this so simple broken down answers would be appreciated! An example would be appreciated too!

Comment: how do you insert the image?

Comment: at the moment we have assigned a class to a div, and then in the CSS we inserted the background image

Answer (score 0):

I do not work to much with yml files but according with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891977/html-inside-translation-message) maybe you can try some like:

```
en:
    logo_html: <img class='eng_img' src='img1.jpg'>
```

and

```
fr:
    logo_html: <img class='fr_img' src='img1.jpg'>
```