# Symfony 3.1 HTML in xlf translation file

Tags: translation, symfony

As recommended by Symfony I'm using xlf files for the translations.

I want to store a message which has a HTML tags, let's say:

```
Welcome back <a href='/user/profile'>user</a>.
```

I have discovered that you can't include this literal in the target section because you get an exception caused by the "<" and ">" chars.

I'm unable to find a way to escape this chars unless using the `&lt;` and `&gt;` .

Is there another solution?. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried with CDATA? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14892213/2270041

Comment: Thanks Matteo. Yes I also found this post and try it. It works but I wonder if there is another simpler way to do it, like % or \ or /......