# Jump a line in XML (or more) - Symfony 3

Tags: xml, symfony

How to actually jump a line in XML? to render it regarding your wishes?

I use translation with Symfony 3 and in my translation folder I would like to jump lines like I would do in html

my translation file (xml)

[image]

and here what it actually renders in my view.html.twig

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need to add `<br>` tag to represent line breaks and use `|raw` filter:

```
{{ 'my.translation.key'|trans|raw }}
```

more information may be found in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14892213/3137047

Comment: Works! but I needed to add that in the XML in order to make it work `<![CDATA[some text.]]>` but works fine! thank you! :)